# How can I set a variable from a promise/observable in Angular after the subscription has completed?

Tags: angular, promise, rxjs, observable

I am making one call to PokeApi to get a list of Pokemon back. I then need to make  a second call to return the sprite images for each Pokemon.

I am able to return the list of Pokemon correctly using rxjs Observables. When this returns the Pokemon name I make a second call to the Pokemon detail to return the sprites. However the second call does not complete in time to return the Pokemon Sprites.

```
public getListOfPokemon(page: number): Observable<Pokemon[]> {
let apiUrl = `${this.apiBaseUrl}/pokemon/?limit=1`;

if (page > 0) {
  let offset = page * 42;

  apiUrl = `${this.apiBaseUrl}/pokemon/?offset=${offset}&limit=42`;
}

return this._httpClient.get(apiUrl).pipe( 
  map((resp: any) => {
    if (resp.results.length == 0) {
      this.lastPageOfResults = resp.next == null;
      this.router.navigate(['/404']);
    }

    this.lastPageOfResults = resp.next == null;

    let pkmnList = _.map(resp.results, (pkmn) => {
      let frontSprite: string;
      let shinySprite: string;

      new Promise(resolve => {
        resolve(this.getPokemonSprites(pkmn.name).subscribe(sprite => {
          return sprite;
        }))
      }).then((value) => {
        console.log(value);
      });

      let singlePkmn = new Pokemon(pkmn.name, frontSprite, shinySprite);

      return singlePkmn;
    });

    return pkmnList;
  })
)
```

}

frontSprite and shinySprite are not set when we return the new Pokemon.

*EDIT*
Here is the getPokemonSprites method for more clarification

```
private getPokemonSprites(name: string): Observable<any> {
let apiUrl = `${this.apiBaseUrl}/pokemon/${name}`;   

return this._httpClient.get(apiUrl).pipe(
  map((pkmnDetail: any) => {
    console.log('hi');
    return pkmnDetail.sprites;
  })
)
```

}

Comment: I’m not exactly sure what you’re looking to do. If you check out the tour of heroes, they cover this pretty extensively. It might be a case where this question can be clarified, but you shouldn’t have to do anything crazy with rxjs to get it to work properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It happens because `promise.then()` performs an async operation. Therefore when you return `new Pokemon()`, the sprite variables may not always be set. So you need to wait for the async operations to complete.

So, for the second mapping, instead of `map` you can use `switchMap` of `rxjs` to subscribe to an inner observable / chain observables. And in `switchMap` you can combine an array of observables with `combineLatest` to get responses of observables as an array.Like below:

```
getPokemons = () => {

    return this._httpClient.get(apiUrl).pipe( 
      map((resp: any) => {
        if (resp.results.length == 0) {
          this.lastPageOfResults = resp.next == null;
          this.router.navigate(['/404']);
        }

        this.lastPageOfResults = resp.next == null;

        return resp.results;
      }),

      switchMap((pokemonList) => {

        const listOfObservables = [];

        _.map(pokemonList, (pkmn) => {
          let frontSprite: string;
          let shinySprite: string;

          const spriteObservable = this.getPokemonSprites(pkmn.name).pipe(
            map((sprite) => {
               let frontSprite = sprite.front_default;
               let shinySprite = sprite.front_shiny;  
               return new Pokemon(pkmn.name, frontSprite, shinySprite);   
            })
          )

          listOfObservables.push(spriteObservable);

        });

        return combineLatest(listOfObservables);
      })
    )
}
```

Then when you call the `getPokemons` (I named it to show how to use) method, it returns a chained observable. When you subscribe, it returns an array of `Pokemon`:

```
getPokemons.subscribe((pokemonList: Array<Pokemon>) => {
    // do the fancy stuff with pokemonList array
})
```

Hope this helps.

---

References:

combineLatest: https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/combination/combinelatest.html

switchMap: https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/transformation/switchmap.html

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't work because spriteObservable is never called to be pushed into the listOfObservables

Comment: I think I found the issue. In `switchMap`, I named the result `pokemonList` but with `_.map()` the iterable is named `pokemon`. I edited the question. Please have a look at.

Comment: Sorry, I had already picked up on this and made the change, still doesn't work I'm afraid

Comment: I have added the getPokemonSprites method to question for more clarity

Comment: Can you create a stackblitz project so that I can help you further?

Comment: Ok I found out what is wrong. 1- You are returning `_.map()` from `switchMap`. You need to remove first `return` and return the `combineLatest`. 2- You are importing wrong `combineLatest`. Try `import { combineLatest } from 'rxjs';` I made changes in stackblitz bu I'm not sure they are persistent. Please let me know if this works.